# How to set textbox background transferent when readonly = true in windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, textbox, windows-phone-8

I want to set the textbox background is tranfernt  when readonly = true i don't want the default color .. can anyone give me solution

I am trying this one but its not working

```
<TextBox Name="MyTextBox" Background="Transparent" Text="My Text" IsReadOnly="True"  />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Setting IsReadOnly on a TextBox applies certain styles to the TextBox including its Background. You can change these styles by doing the following:

- Open your xaml file in Blend from within Visual Studio
- In Blend, right click on your TextBox and click on Edit Template-->Edit Copy
- In the next dialog, tick Application to define the new style in App.xaml and give your style a name.
- Click save and close Blend.

You will see the new style that you just created is in App.xaml. You would want to change the value of `Background` story board target property under the `ReadOnly` visual state to whichever color you want.

To apply this new style to any TextBox just add `Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}"` to your TextBox where `TextBoxStyle1` is the name you assigned to your style.

Edit:

Here is the full style, add it in App.xaml inside `<Application.Resources>`

```xml
     <Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"/>
                        <Border x:Name="ReadonlyBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Then in your text box you simply point to this style:

```xml
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle1}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to set the TextBox IsHitTestVisible=false. The field is then also not editable by the user and you can set the background as usual.

By the way, setting a different border color of a disabled textbox can be done application wide programmatically:

```
(App.Current.Resources["PhoneDisabledBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color = Colors.Magenta;
```

Answer (score 0):

[RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) allows a lot of customization and works well for when you want to register events. Note that IsReadOnly is [set to true by default for RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.isreadonly%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) so you do not need to set this property.